# DeleteDuplicates not deleting duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

It is not surprising that `DeleteDuplicates[{5,5.}]` returns `{5,5.}` because `DeleteDuplicates` uses `SameQ` by default, and `SameQ[5,5.]` is `False`.

However, `Equal[5,5.]` is `True`, but `DeleteDuplicates[{5,5.},Equal]` still returns `{5,5.}`.

It is interesting to note that `Union` works properly, in that `Union[{5,5.},SameTest->Equal]` returns `{5}`, as expected.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I'm using version 9.

**Update:**

I realize that using the function `#1==#2&` will get it working, thanks for pointing this out.

However, my question really is "Is this a bug, or am I missing something?".

To illustrate this further, consider the following:

```
f[x__]:=Equal[x]
DeleteDuplicates[{5,5.},f]
(* {5} *)
```

In what capacity are `f` and `Equal` different? Or what is leading `DeleteDuplicates` to treat them differently? They both take an arbitrary number of inputs, which is what I originally thought was the problem.

Comment: Try `DeleteDuplicates[{5, 5.}, #1 == #2 &]`.

Comment: @TomD I don't get that. Still `{5, 5.}` here on v9

Comment: I'm reporting this as a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: wouldn't it make sense to add that as an answer: it looks like a bug and the reason is presumably (?) that the `Equal` case is treated as a special case for performance reaons. I think it would be most convincing if such an answer would come from you :-)

Comment: But @Albert Retey, are you saying that you won't believe me in a comment, but you will in an answer?

Comment: ... it might also be of interest that this behavior is new to version 9, version 7 and 8 give the "expected" result...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: no of course not, I think it would give the OP the chance to accept that answer and mark the question as "solved". Comments, AFAIK, are to be considered only as second class citizens here, probably not even here to stay...

Comment: (Sigh) @Albert Retey, I forgot your country of origin...

Comment: @TomD As Albert says above, this behaviour is new in v9...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: sorry, I didn't get that last one. What I wanted to say is that it makes a difference whether I call it a bug or you, not so much because you live in Champaign but because of your employer...

Comment: @Albert Retey I'm just kidding around, not to worry.

Comment: Meta question: If this question ever gets a duplicate, will we be able to delete it?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You're really inspired today. Go write a paper.

Comment: @belisarius I'm afraid it's one of those days where the insanity is driving me crazy.

Comment: Fixed in version 10!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @Albert Retey remarked in a comment, a second argument of (just) Equal leads to a special case handler that, to me, seems overly ambitious. I reported it as a bug.

Comment: +1 but... raking in rep for confirming bugs may be the wrong incentive, WRI-wise? :-P

Comment: My strategy has been to fix bugs/implement features, remain silent for weeks/months, and then miss the rep uptick when the new version ships because sleep started to look better than beating out intrepid explorers for reputation.  Maybe I should rethink that... :)

Comment: @Yves Klett I'm as confused as you. Meanwhile other responses take real work and get maybe 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use :

```
DeleteDuplicates[{5, 5.}, Equal[#1, #2] &]
(* {5} *)
```

Comment: Something like `Unevaluated@Identity@Equal` will work a bit faster I think