# Consistently annoying error messages in Mathematica 9

Tags: warning-messages, version-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange ::usage behavior in v9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18549/strange-usage-behavior-in-v9)

Has anyone had any issues with a function, let's call it Function, which worked in Mathematica 8 getting the error message

StringMatchQ::strse: "String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[!($Failed, \"Function*\")]"

This message occurs not after the function is evaluated, but instead a dialogue box appears if one uses the backspace key while typing the arguments of the function.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that produces this problem?