# Custom Graphics primitives can't work with parallel Rasterize

Tags: graphics, parallelization, image, undocumented, rasterize

I tried to create Graphics primitives using the techniques in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/how-to-create-custom-graphics-primitive), found problems with parallel rasterization

```
SetAttributes[createPrimitive,HoldAll];

createPrimitive[patt_,expr_]:=Typeset`MakeBoxes[p:patt,fmt_,Graphics]:=Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[expr,p],fmt,Graphics];

createPrimitive[face[x_:0.1],{Circle[{0,0},1],Circle[{-0.3,0.5},x],Circle[{0.3,0.5},x],Line[{{-0.4,-0.2},{0.4,-0.2}}]}];

ParallelTable[Graphics[{face[i]},ImageSize->Tiny],{i,0,0.3,0.3/5}]
ParallelTable[Rasterize@Graphics[{face[i]},ImageSize->Tiny],{i,0,0.3,0.3/5}]
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Your problem is that "face" is not defined.

Comment: @DanielHuber No, things defined with Typeset`MakeBoxes, the FrontEnd doesn't color.

Comment: Type `?? face`  and you will see that face is not defined. Or look at the color.

Comment: @DanielHuber As mentioned by OP, in this case we've just added a down value for ``Typeset`MakeBoxes``, try ``#[[Position[#, face[__], Infinity] // Flatten // First]] &[
 DownValues@Typeset`MakeBoxes]``. For more info, please read the linked post in the question carefully.

Comment: @xzczd  Tnank you for the hint, I did not know this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is probably related to [*Parallel evaluation of Image and Rasterize problem*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42624/parallel-evaluation-of-image-and-rasterize-problem). Briefly, `Rasterize` is not done by the kernel but by the front-end.

For example, when you don't include rasterization, the output of `ParallelTable` is still `Graphics[{face[...]}]`, and it is then the main front-end that afterwards converts this to your shapes.

```
ParallelTable[InputForm@Graphics[{face[i]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], {i, {0, .2}}]
(* {Graphics[{face[0]}, ImageSize -> Tiny],
    Graphics[{face[0.2]}, ImageSize -> Tiny]} *)

ParallelTable[ToBoxes@Graphics[{face[i]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], {i, {0, .2}}]
(* {GraphicsBox[{face[0]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
    GraphicsBox[{face[0.2]}, ImageSize -> Tiny]}
```

Therefore, you need to somehow get your definitions to the front-ends that are initiated by the subkernels. [`DistributeDefinitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) doesn't work, but [`ParallelEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) seems to do the job. Maybe there are also some other viable solutions.

```
ParallelEvaluate[
 SetAttributes[createPrimitive, HoldAll];
 createPrimitive[patt_, expr_] := 
  Typeset`MakeBoxes[p : patt, fmt_, Graphics] := 
   Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[expr, p], fmt, Graphics];
 createPrimitive[
  face[x_ : 0.1], {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{-0.3, 0.5}, x], 
   Circle[{0.3, 0.5}, x], Line[{{-0.4, -0.2}, {0.4, -0.2}}]}];];

ParallelTable[Rasterize@Graphics[{face[i]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], {i, 0, 0.3, 0.3/5}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is surprising. BTW it's worth mentioning that `DistributedContexts->All` doesn't work, either. (+1, of course. )