# $Failed below input area of new cell in notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, initialization

The *Mathematica* 9 installation on my laptop has developed an odd feature.  Just underneath the grey line indicating the input area for a new cell, the expression `$Failed` appears in small type at the left hand end.

This occurs even before I type anything in a fresh notebook created at start-up.  I tried deleting both the `Kernel`'s and `FrontEnd`'s init.m files but that did not help.   As soon as I start to type an input, it disappears.   It doesn't seem to interfere with kernel evaluations but is just annoying.

[image: This is how it looks in a new notebook created at start-up.]

Comment: OK, I added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: I would try resetting preferences to their defaults. Maybe you are automatically evaluating some notebook at startup (which contains some kind of error). For example: Preferences->Global Options->File Locations has the option to AutoOpenNotebooks.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to help.  I am wondering now if this $Failed is coming from the Front End Kernel, as described at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/why-are-there-two-separate-mathkernel-processes-running-when-i-start-up-mathemat

Comment: Re-installing Mathematica fixed it.