# Package function not called from button in a DockedCell expression

Tags: version-10

Consider the following minimal example package:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];

DuplicateNotebook::usage = "Makes a copy of the notebook";

Begin["`Private`"];

DuplicateNotebook[] := 
  NotebookPut @ NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]];
  ex2 = 
    Grid[{{Item[ButtonBar[{
        Style["Duplicate", 10] :> DuplicateNotebook[],
        Style["Quit Kernel", 10] :> FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorQuit"]}], 
      Alignment -> {Right, Top}]}}];
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ex2]], "SystemDockedCell"]];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

**So what's happening?**

The function `DuplicateNotebook[]` defined in the package doesn't get called when the button is clicked, but calls of type `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorQuit"]` work.

What's more, this code was working perfectely well in *Mathematica* V9, but now in *Mathematica* V10, I can't get it working without putting the function body directly into `DockedCells`, which of course is a very messy solution. Therefore I'm looking for better workarounds.

This seems to be a problem with `DockedCells` context, because putting the cell in the notebook (not in `DockedCells`) works. However adding context information to the call didn't work (I've tried `` Test`DuplicateNotebook[] ``)

Zipped version of the test package http://cl.ly/2C3U2O2n0y21

Comment: You may have found a bug, but don't use the `bugs` tag for suspected bugs. It is reserved for marking ***confirmed*** bugs.

Comment: If you change the action to `Print[DownValues[DuplicateNotebook]]`, it strangely prints `{}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the action is not evaluated in the same kernel that we are using for computation.  We can change the action to `Print[$SessionID]` and compare it with the `$SessionID` of the main kernel.  They will differ.

Could it be that the action is evaluated in the private kernel instance used by the front end?  See here:

- [Why are there two separate MathKernel processes running when I start up Mathematica 9?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/why-are-there-two-separate-mathkernel-processes-running-when-i-start-up-mathemat)

I tested this in version 8 and version 9 as well.  The service kernel was introduced in version 9.  Version 9 behaves the same as version 10.  In version 8, the button behaves as you'd expect: it duplicates the notebook.

This all suggests that the button action is evaluated in the service kernel.  `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorQuit"]` works because it is ultimately evaluated by the front end, not the kernel.

This all happens only if you use the `"SystemDockedCell"` style, but not otherwise (so there's your fix).  For this reason I suspect that this is a deliberate design decision and not a bug.

Looking at the `"SystemDockedCell"` style in `Core.nb`, it has the option `Evaluator -> "System"` set.

Comment: I'd never suspect that a style change could make such a difference and I probably changed the style around the time of _Mathematica_ V10 coming out, so it looked like it worked in _Mathematica_ V9, but not in _Mathematica_ V10. Anyway, thanks!