# Custom drop-down list of tags for Dataset Keys similar to CountryData

Tags: dataset, entity

`CountryData` produces a drop-down list of tags when you enter a string.

I would like to replicate this functionality for a `Dataset` I have created, so I would have a function that lists the `Dataset` `Keys` as I start typing the string (as there are a large number of `Keys`).

Creating a custom `Entity` would seem to be one route but it seems that this is not possible? Any ideas?

Comment: In recent versions of Mathematica [it's not possible to hack auto-completion any more](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16599/12) because [it's running on a separate kernel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/why-are-there-two-separate-mathkernel-processes-running-when-i-start-up-mathemat).  I believe that what  you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, shame but good to know!