# Enable file completion by default?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

File completions work for Import and Get but not with << syntax as you can see:

[image]

Is there some way to enable this?

Comment: No, there isn't.  See the link to the WTC2015 talk by John Fultz I posted on your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible as of version 11.0.0.

[Since version 9.0.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16710/12), auto-completion is handled by [a separate service kernel process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21870/12) which is for the exclusive use of the front end and is not user-programmable.

At the [WTC 2015](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/presentations/), John Fultz showed a prototype of user-programmable auto-completion, but this doesn't seem to be present in version 11.0.0 yet.