# Macro functions in GeneralUtilities?

Tags: meta-programming, general-utilities

Questions have been asked about the Macros package before (e.g., [(83815)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83815/18476)), but I'm interested if anyone has some examples of using the macro related functions in GeneralUtilities:

```
In[2397]:= Names["GeneralUtilities`*Macro*"]

Out[2397]= {"DefineLiteralMacro", "DefineMacro", "MacroEvaluate", \
"MacroExpand", "MacroExpandList", "MacroPanic", "MacroRules", \
"UseMacros", "$MacroDebugMode"}
```

I find their docstrings a bit cryptic:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only official information about the `Macro` functions I am aware of can be found in a short segment in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2tr7A1LOLA&feature=youtu.be&t=1043), which describes the "Macro System" as an essential part of the next compiler generation. However, the `CreateMExpr` shown there isn't included in *Mathematica* 10.4.1. (But maybe someone can find parts of it digging deeper into it?)

Nevertheless, one can already apply the Macro System practically (while being aware that this is an undocumented functionality with all the consequences involved) outside of that next generation compiler context.

First let's load the `GeneralUtilities` package and see what `Macro` functions are available as of version 10.4.1.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
Names["*Macro*"]
```

> ```
> {"DefineLiteralMacro", "DefineMacro", "MacroEvaluate", "MacroExpand", "MacroExpandList", 
>  "MacroPanic", "MacroRules", "UseMacros", $MacroDebugMode"}
> ```

First

```
?MacroRules
```

[image: MacroRulesUsage]

can be used to see how macros are defined within *Mathematica*. The most illustrating example is

```
MacroRules[DoWhile]
```

[image: DoWhileMacro]

One can get an overview of all predefined macros (that I found) using

```
MacroRules /@ List @@ GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`$MacroHeadsPattern //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```

The `Panel`s are how `Quoted` code is displayed in the Front End.

```
?Quoted
```

[image: Quoded_Usage]

## Example 1: Simple Syntactical Sugar

Let's assume we don't like the common [`Increment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Increment.html) syntax and want to use an `incr` function instead.

```
DefineMacro[incr, incr[n_] := Quoted[n++]]
```

[image: incrMacro]

`incr` itself doesn't have any [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html), therefore

```
counter = 0;
Table[incr[counter], 5]
```

> `{incr[0], incr[0], incr[0], incr[0], incr[0]}`

The macro can be applied using

```
MacroEvaluate@Table[incr[counter], 5]
```

> `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`

To see what the macro does, one can use

```
MacroExpand@Table[incr[counter], 5]
```

[image: MacroExpand_incr]

and

```
MacroExpandList@Table[incr[counter], 5]
```

[image: MacroExpandList_incr]

## Example 2: Code Refactoring Macro

Let's say we have some code that contains some `Table` expressions in the form `Table[expr, n]` and we want to replace them with `Array` and add 1 to every `expr`. To do this a macro can be defined in the following way:

```
DefineMacro[macro1, macro1[Table[expr_, n_?IntegerQ]] := Quoted[Array[1 + expr &, n]]]
```

[image: macro1]

Just applying `macro1` to a `Table` does nothing special

```
macro1[Table[RandomReal[], 5]]
```

> `macro1[{0.0977249, 0.987251, 0.484049, 0.712003, 0.358444}]`

but

```
MacroEvaluate@macro1@Table[RandomReal[], 5]
```

> `{1.60094, 1.53355, 1.49432, 1.74318, 1.648}`

does make use of the macro.

```
MacroExpand[macro1[Table[RandomReal[], 5]]]
```

[image: MacroExpand_macro1]

```
MacroExpandList[macro1[Table[RandomReal[], 5]]]
```

[image: MacroExpandList_macro1]

If one tries to apply this macro to a `Table` having a different syntax pattern a `Failure` message is created.

```
MacroExpand[macro1[Table[RandomReal[], {i, 5}]]]
```

[image: FailureMessage]

Using replacement rules instead of a macro is less convenient, as the syntax is more complex.

```
Unevaluated@
  Table[RandomReal[], 5] /. {Verbatim[Table][expr_, n_?IntegerQ] :> Array[1 + expr &, n], 
                             ___ -> $Failed}
```

> `{1.14275, 1.55058, 1.13318, 1.05475, 1.75428}`

## Example 3: Code Refactoring for Performance Tuning and `Compile`

Let's assume we have defined a function

```
f[n_] := Table[RandomReal[], n]
```

and now we realize that for big integers `n` this implementation does perform much worse than `RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]`. A macro can be used to refactor our code.

```
DefineMacro[f, f[n_] := Quoted[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n] + 1]]
```

(The `+ 1` is just added to directly judge by the output, if the macro has been applied.)

For small `n` the overhead of using the Macro System does outweigh the performance increase of not using `Table`,

```
Table[RandomReal[], 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10] + 1; // AbsoluteTiming
MacroEvaluate[f[10]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000126977, Null}
> {8.35374*10^-6, Null}
> {0.0000110269, Null}
> {0.00018278, Null}
> ```

but becomes neglectable for big `n`.

```
f[1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
MacroEvaluate[f[1000000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0549422, Null}
> {0.0149402, Null}
> ```

One interesting thing to note is that the macro gets automatically applied when `f` is used to define an other function. For example

```
g[m_] := f[m]

DownValues@g
```

> `{HoldPattern[g[m_]] :> RandomReal[{0, 1}, m] + 1}`

That this will be happening in other cases too becomes evident by looking at

```
 ?? f
```

Using the Macro System is also very helpful in conjunction with `Compile`.

```
cf = MacroEvaluate@Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
   f[n]
   ]

CompilePrint@cf
```

[image: CompilePrint@cf]

Here using `MacroEvaluate` has two effects:

1. The macro for `f` gets applied and therefore the more efficient version is compiled.
2. `f[n]` can directly been put into `Compile`.

Without the Macro System directly using `f[n]` inside `Compile` results in a call to `MainEvaluate`.

```
Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}},
  f[n]
  ] // CompilePrint
```

[image: CompilePrint]

Comment: The Macro System seems to be inspired by Lisp macros. As I have no experience with Lisp, maybe someone who does can add more useful examples in their answer. I'd also appreciate comments correcting my terminology or usage & understanding of macros.

Comment: Nice information.  Before, if I wanted to have functions to be processed by `Compile` in a different way, I always defined ``Internal`CompileValues`` for them.  I look forward to the new `Macro` system.