# What's the purpose of the GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions?

Tags: undocumented, built-in-symbols

```
?? GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions
```

[image]

```
    HoldPattern[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`s:(_=_GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions)]^:=
GeneralUtilities`MacroEvaluate[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`s]

    HoldPattern[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`sd:(_:=_GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions)]^:=
GeneralUtilities`MacroEvaluate[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`sd]

    HoldPattern[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`tsd:(_/:_:=_GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions)]^:=
GeneralUtilities`MacroEvaluate[GeneralUtilities`Control`PackagePrivate`tsd]
```

If we use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` we'll get:
[image]

As the information,the `` GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions `` seem to can extracts the definition of a certain option?But how to use it?

Comment: Related, possibly: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114184/macro-functions-in-generalutilities

Comment: @yode I don't have `UnpackOptions` in version 10.1.0.  Would you please include the function definition in your question?  I have an idea of what this may be for but I need to see more.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good link.Thanks. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(analysis current as of Mathematica V11.0.1)*

`UnpackOptions` is a macro that provides a convenient notation for accessing option values within a function definition.

At definition time, it transforms a source macro expression of the form:

```
UnpackOptions[option1, option2]
```

into an expanded expression of the form:

```
{option1, option2} = OptionValue @ {"Option1", "Option2"}
```

Note how the actual option names are generated automatically from the variable names which will receive the option values.  The first character of the option name will be capitalized unless the variable name starts with a "$" (which will be dropped from the option name).

**Examples**

Examples of `UnpackOptions` can be found in numerous source files distributed with *Mathematica*.  Here is one:

```
{ $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components"
, "MXNetLink", "Kernel", "DataIterators.m"
} // FileNameJoin // NotebookOpen
```

For instance, the definition of `MXDataRandomizer` starts like this:

```
MXDataRandomizer[assoc_Association, OptionsPattern[]] := CatchFailure @ Scope[
    UnpackOptions[context, dataType];
    If[!AllSameBy[Values@assoc, Length], Panic["DifferentLengths"]];
    ...
```

If we load this package and inspect the in-memory definition of `MXDataRandomizer`, we will find the expanded macro:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
Needs["MXNetLink`"]

PrintDefinitionsLocal[MXDataRandomizer]

(*
    MXDataRandomizer[assoc_Association, OptionsPattern[]] := Catch[
        Block[{context, dataType, randIndices, randomizedAssoc},
            {context, dataType} = OptionValue @ {"Context", "DataType"};
            If[!AllSameBy[Values @ assoc, Length],
            ...
*)
```

Also note how the macro `CatchFailure` expanded into a `Catch` expression, and how the implicit scoping macro `Scope` expanded into an explicit `Block` construct.
*[as an aside, the use of Block here instead of Module is very dodgy]*

**Viewing Macro Definitions**

The definition of `UnpackOptions` itself, along with many other macros, can be inspected by evaluating:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions[MacroRules]
```

**Ensuring Macros Get Triggered**

Beware that macros are only expanded when they appear as the top-level head on the right-hand side of a definition.  This limitation is due to the fact that macros are implemented as up-values on `Set`, `SetDelayed` and `TagSetDelayed`.

Since `UnpackOptions` is not useful as a top-level expression, it needs to be contained within another macro to be used effectively.  In the case of `MXDataRandomizer` it was contained within the body of the top-level macro `CatchFailure`.

Should we not want to use other macros like `CatchFailure` or `Scope`, there is a convenient macro called `UseMacros` that will do nothing but trigger macro expansion:

```
Options[f] = {A -> 10, B -> 20};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  UseMacros @ Module[{a, b}, UnpackOptions[a, b]; {x, a, b}]

f[1]
(* {1, 10, 20} *)
```

Comment: I don't have the function, or `MacroEvaluate`, in 10.1.0 but this is exactly what I thought it might do.  I have seen that expansion many times internally and I even wrote my own version of this once.  Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. :-)